# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_filters'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, database-migration, django-filter

I deleted the pycache, migrations and DB of my code to start migrations again. But I realized that there might be another way to do it, so I discarded all the changes in VS code. I tried pulling the code from master, just in case. But it showed me that my branch was already up to date with master. So I ran makemigrations, but as I tried doing that, it showed me this error:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_filters'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 599, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 584, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 299, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 305, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 345, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 361, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 260, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 105, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
e 141, in iter_modules_and_files
    resolved_path = path.resolve(strict=True).absolute()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\pathlib.py", line 1166, in resolve
    s = self._flavour.resolve(self, strict=strict)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\pathlib.py", line 200, in resolve
    return self._ext_to_normal(_getfinalpathname(s))
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

This has happened quite a lot times, and I cant seem to find a solution to it.
How do I resolve it?

Here is my settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'django_filters',
    'dashboard.apps.DashboardConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = { 'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'rest_framework.schemas.coreapi.AutoSchema' }
```

On doing `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, i see this:

```
asgiref==3.2.7
astroid==2.4.0
colorama==0.4.3
Django==3.0.7
django-extensions==2.2.9
django-filter==1.1.0
django-smart-selects==1.5.6
djangorestframework==3.11.0
djangorestframework-filters==0.11.1
drfdocs==0.0.11
graphviz==0.14
isort==4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
mccabe==0.6.1
pydotplus==2.0.2
pylint==2.5.0
pylint-django==2.0.15
pylint-plugin-utils==0.6
pyparsing==2.4.7
pytz==2020.1
six==1.13.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
toml==0.10.0
wrapt==1.11.2
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your version is very old (https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/tree/56eaae15e4fab97483e1353080a0c320f18c1014#requirements)

and try moving below

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'dashboard.apps.DashboardConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework',
    'django_filters',
]
```

Comment: I tried moving it below. But what should I do about the version? I recently installed it

Comment: Besides, I was not getting any error before I deleted stuff. The code was working fine an hour ago

Comment: pip install django-filter (your version django-filter==1.1.0 last version 2.3.0)

Comment: I didnt get you. I uninstalled django-filter in my virtual env and installed it again. Still the error persists

Answer (score 0):

**Please install django-filter package and add to installed apps**

```
pip install django-filter
```

Then add 'django_filters' to your INSTALLED_APPS.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django_filters',
]
```